# Setting vars using for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I have the following javascript

```
information0 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")[0].textContent; 
information1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")[1].textContent;
information2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")[2].textContent; 
information3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")[3].textContent;
information4 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")[4].textContent;
information5 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")[5].textContent;
information6 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info")[6].textContent;
```

I want to create a new var for each index number. There are 600 in total. How can I do this using a for loop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not hold it in an array

Comment: You can use an `Array` -- `information = []; information[0] = xmlDoc...; ...`

Comment: Ok so I have seen all your answers, but I need to call them like this 

'document.write(information0 + "<br>");
document.write(information1 + "<br>");
document.write(information2 + "<br>");
document.write(information3 + "<br>");
document.write(information4 + "<br>");
document.write(information5 + "<br>");
document.write(information6 + "<br>");'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing here is to use an *array*, not a bunch of individual variables.

```
var information = [];
var index;
var info = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info");
for (index = 0; index < info.length; ++index) {
    information[index] = info[index].textContent;
}
```

Comment: So I thought using this i could them back by using: 
`document.write(information0 + "<br>");`
But I'm not able to

Comment: @craig: `document.write` has basically no place in modern web applications. If you use it after the initial page parsing, it causes an implicit `document.open`, which wipes out the content of the page. But to access this information later, you use the same sort of notation: `doSomethingWith(information[0]);` or `doSomethingWith(information[index]);` where `index` is one of the array indexes.

Comment: Ok so should alert(information0) work? I can't even seem to make that work

Comment: My apologies. Missed out the square brackets! Best answer

Comment: @craig, You should still have a look at mine for some additionnal important information.

Answer (score 1):

Um... use an array? Also, don't call `getElementsByTagName` repeatedly, it's expensive!

```
var tags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('info'), l = tags.length, i, information = [];
for( i=0; i<l; i++) information[i] = tags[i].textContent;
```

If you're in a reasonably up-to-date browser:

```
var information = [].map.call(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('info'),function(a) {return a.textContent;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var information = [],
    i,
    elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info"),
    n = elements.length;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    information[i] = elements[i].textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array.

```
var infoTags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("info"),
    i = 0,
    len = infoTags.length,
    values = []; //array literal syntax, you could also use new Array()

for (; i < len; i++) {
    values.push(infoTags[i].textContent); //push the textContent into the array
}
```

Things that you should note:

- I cached the result of `getElementsByTagName` instead of performing the query multiple times.
- I cached the `length` property of `infoTags`. That avoids multiple property lookups to access `infoTags.length` on every iterations. Property lookups are expensive in JavaScript.

To know how you can work with arrays, have a look at the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object.
 -

Comment: If you're worried about expense, don't needlessly call `push`. But I challenge your assertion that using `len` rather than `infoTags.length` makes any real-world difference for 600 elements. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Perhaps not, but it's definitely a better practice and I believe it's worth mentionning.

Comment: Adding a variable for no real benefit? Not *necessarily*. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well I fear we will have to agree to disagree.